# Reversing typeof to use Linq Field<T>

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, casting

I want to use Linq to dynamically select DataTable columns by ColumnName but to use Field<> I must explicitly cast them or box everything to an object, which is not efficient.

I tried:

```
string[] colsNames = new[] { "Colum1", "Colum2" };
DataTable dt = StoredProcedure().Tables[0];

var cols = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => cols.Contains(c.ColumnName));

if (cols.Any())
{
    dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => string.Join(":", cols.Select(c => r.Field<c.DataType>(c.ColumnName))))
}
```

but this throws me an error `The type or namespace name 'c' could not be found`

How do I convert `typeof(decimal)` to `Field<decimal>("Column1")` for example?

Comment: What the point? If you don't know type of requested data, then all you can handle is an `object`

Comment: I do know the type of requested data

Comment: But you said that you are retrieving data by column name.. Then what's wrong with `IEnumerable<known_type> requestedData = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<known_type>("ColumnName"))` ?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky because I am selecting columns dynamically.

Comment: then you don't know type of requested data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt.Columns.Add("Colum1", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt.Columns.Add("Colum2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("Colum3");

string[] colsNames = new[] { "Colum1", "Colum2" };
var colTypes = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                 .Where(c => colsNames.Contains(c.ColumnName))
                 .Select(c => new
                 {
                     c.ColumnName,
                     c.DataType
                 })
                 .ToDictionary(key => key.ColumnName, val => val.DataType);

var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(row => (int)row["id"]==5)
              .Select(row => new
              {
                  Colum1 = Convert.ChangeType(row[colsNames[0]], colTypes[colsNames[0]]),
                  Colum2 = Convert.ChangeType(row[colsNames[1]], colTypes[colsNames[1]])
              });
```

Here is another variant, but it is not very interesting:

```
//define class
public class myClass
{
    public int Column1;
    public string Column2;
}
// then
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .Select(row => new myClass
              {
                  Column1 = Convert.ToInt32(row[colsNames[0]]),
                  Column2 = row[colsNames[1]].ToString()
              });
```

There is a third variant: you can create a view or stored procedure in the database and add it to the data context

Comment: Can't +1. Not enough credits. +1 for the ChangeType. I will try to implement it in my solution.

Comment: Ok, place + later, although not necessarily :)

Comment: It would be enough to do `Colum1 = row[0]`, it's already typed.

Comment: @Boris. I don't think the solution works. If I do `query.GetType();` I get `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[System.Object]` but not `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[System.Decimal]` as required

Comment: the way it should be. If you want System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[System.Decimal] you should write .Select(row => Convert.ChangeType(row[colsNames[5]], colTypes[colsNames[5]] )), but it's not what you want, is not? To get decimal write: foreach(var q in query) q.Column5 ...

Comment: @Boris still gives me `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[System.Object]`

Comment: @BorisGappov. I need to dynamically select columns from a datatable, if I knew that the first column was an Int, then I could just use Field<int>()

Comment: c# is not javascript, use anonimous classes or use own class