# How to dynamically add properties to a LINQ GroupBy clause

Tags: linq, dynamic, group-by

I have a class `Product`:

```
class Product
{ 
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   int CategoryId { get; set; }
   int PlantId { get; set; }
   DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use the `LINQ GroupBy` on multiple properties but I do not know in advance how many and which properties. For instance I might want to group by just `CategoryId`, just `PlantId` or both. I found an article on the net that describes how to [use LINQ GrouBy dinamically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2008/02/07/linq-groupbymany-dynamically.aspx).

This might work good indeed but if I want to perform the Group By on `ProductionDate.Year` and `ProductionDate.Month` without knowing the granularity in advance? As granularity I mean whether I want to group all the `Products` produced in a specific year or narrow the group by to the month.

The only logical solution that I found is:

```
public ProductInfo GetGroupedProducts(int? year, int? month, int? selectedCategoryId, int? selectedPlantId)
{
List<Product> products = GetProducts();

var groupedProducts = products.GroupBy(p => new { (year == null ? p.ProductionDate.Year : string.Empty),
                                                  (month == null ? p.ProductionDate.Month : string.Empty),
                                                  (selectedCategoryId == null ? p.CategoryId : string.Empty),
                                                  (selectedPlantId == null ? p.PlantId : string.Empty)
});

//perform some additional filtering and assignments 

}
```

But I guess there could be a cleaner and more proper solution. With the old style way of building queries, based on strings, this task was much easier to accomplish. If there is no other way, I really think this is a part of `LINQ` that needs to be improved.

Comment: Well, I'd use `bool` parameters rather than `int?`...

Comment: A method `GetGroupedProducts` that returns _void_?

Comment: @Rawling: I use int? becuase after the GroupBy I also perform some filtering

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I can change the return type but I do not think it is relevant with the question's context

Comment: Since you're already passing in a parameter per field you might want to group on, there's nothing very dynamic you _can_ do - or rather, _need_ to do. (As opposed to, for example, if you were to be passing in a `string[]` of field names, where you'd need to use reflection or similar to get the correct properties.)

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner solution is to use this extension method:

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput? o, Func<TInput, TResult>
    selector, TResult defaultResult = default(TResult)) where TInput : struct
{
    return o.HasValue ? selector(o.Value) : defaultResult;
}
```

Like this:

```
string result = year.With(T => p.ProductionDate.Year, string.Empty);
```

of this, if nulls are okay:

```
string result = year.With(T => p.ProductionDate.Year);
```

or something with `T` which is `int` in case the `int?` has value.

---

But, you know, the better solution is [out there](https://www.google.ru/search?q=the+truth+is+out+there&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbo=u&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=_JS8UKKrKsSK4gSn04CwCA&sqi=2&ved=0CE0QsAQ&biw=1920&bih=979), so feel free to expand your code so I could analyze it.

Comment: Your generic types are inconsistent - `o` is `int?` but `selector` is `Func<Product, int>` and `defaultResult` is `string`. (Although admittedly the `TResult` disagreement comes from the question.)

Comment: @Rawling because `p` is used from Linq query, and the `T` is different lambda. Both do not interfere each other.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Still, it says a lot that the original code was immediately apparent to me, whereas this confused me. This is really just a wrapper for the ternary operation.

Comment: (Actually, if you just called this `SelectOrDefault` or something like that, I'd have probably understood a lot quicker :) )

Comment: @Rawling not just a wrapper. Its a full fluent-syntaxed support for objects traversal. Called [the maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#The_Maybe_monad).

Comment: Hm. I can see how if you have a lot of nested nullable `struct`s this would let you select a deep value or null without having to worry about if an intermediate "layer" is null, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Rawling Correct. It also works on the second overload which accepts references instead of structs. So you could use `p.With(T => T.Data).If(T => T.Items.Length > 0).With(T => T.Items[0])` ... etc. THere are many uses of this monad.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, I had a similar issue [Reversing typeof to use Linq Field<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550353/reversing-typeof-to-use-linq-fieldt)

I would do something like

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, TElement>> GroupMany<TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, 
    params Func<TElement, object>[] groupSelectors)
    {
        return elements.GroupBy(e => string.Join(":", groupSelectors.Select(s => s(e))));
    }
```

then you can call your function like

```
var groupedProducts = products.GroupMany(p => p.CategoryId , p => p.ProductionDate.Month);
```

The function groups via a string of the properties divided by a colon. The reason why I did this is because the hashcode for strings are guaranteed to be the same as opposed to a class.